# adapter.update

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, dataadapter

i make the adapter.insert and the adapter.delete and both work good but not with the adapter.delete even i put only on argument here the code

Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        usersAdp.Fill(userstable)
        usersAdp.Update(txtid.Text, Me.txtname.Text, Me.txtemail.Text, Me.txtpassword.Text, Me.txtconfirm.Text, Me.txtcode.Text, Me.CheckBox1.Checked = True)
        Me.GridView1.DataSource = userstable
        Me.GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub

Comment: Please reformat your question, if you want anyone to answer you, you have got to put in more effort.

Comment: this is the error with the usersAdp.Update
overload resolution failed because no accessible 'update' can be accept this number of argument

Comment: Under your question you should see an edit link. Click that, then highlight the code segment in your original question. Click the "101010" button at the top of the editor. That should allow your code to be formatted so we can read it easier. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What is the datasource for this adapter - if its an SQL table, has it got a primary key defined?

When you type the usersAdp.Update method, the intellisense should give you the options with various numbers of parameters and types of parameters that are legal combinations. Make sure you pass it the number and parameter types that are one of the legal options.

Comment: Thanks, Primary Key sorted it for me :)